# Passing array from system verilog to VHDL

Tags: arrays, generics, parameter-passing, vhdl, system-verilog

I have a code in VHDL which requires an array of elements as generic. 
COEF_LIST            : coef  :=(0,0,1,1,2,-2,1,-2,1)

How do I send new set of COEF_LIST from my system verilog testbench to VHDL entity?

Generic in VHDL is same as parameter in verilog.

I declared coef as

```
  parameter  real COEFF[8:0] = '{0,0,1,1,2,-2,1,-2,1};
```

in system verilog.

I tried passing using (in my verilog testbench)

```
 vhdl_entity  #(
                 .COEF_LIST(COEFF)
               )
```

I get the following error

```
                 **.COEF_LIST(COEFF)
                                |
```

ncelab: *E,CFIGTC (./vhdl_entity_tb.vams,41|36): VHDL generic   vhdl_entity.COEF_LIST (../views/rtl/vhdl_entity.vhd: line 34, position 14) type is not compatible with Verilog.
irun: *E,ELBERR: Error during elaboration (status 1), exiting.**

This doesn't work. How do I make it compatible with VHDL?
I am using incisiv 13.20.008 version

Could anyone please suggest what to do?

Comment: Can you give more details of what goes wrong? (Preferably by editing your post)

Comment: Try simplifying the problem by setting a default argument on the VHDL entity to see if that works. You have declared as an array of real but the VHDL elaborator may be seeing the array as a list of integers. See what happens when you add decimal points to the numbers.

Comment: Post the declaration of the VHDL entity (just the generic would be enough, no ports) to better show what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you declared your COEF_LIST as an array of integers in VHDL, whereas you are trying to pass an array of reals from SystemVerilog. Try changing to:

```
parameter int COEFF[8:0] = '{0,0,1,1,2,-2,1,-2,1};
```

Comment: Assuming `COEF_LIST : coef :=(0,0,1,1,2,-2,1,-2,1)` is a generic declaration in a generic interface list, the type declaration for `coef` is not knowable from the information present.  Your answer works only if the array type `coef` has a base type of integer and incisiv provides implicit type conversion.  This seems like a type incompatibility issue between two language domains requiring fixes in both domains.

Comment: @DavidKoontz Hence the "seems like" in the answer and not "because".